# Spring MVC (подключение static файлов)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

При попытке подключить статик JS файл к представлению сталкиваюсь с ошибкой net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) в браузере. Добавил в конфигурацию (нагуглил)

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/js/");

    }
```

сначала пробовал создать static папку в recources директории, потом начитал в интернете что этот вариант предназначен для Spring Boot и переместил в WEB-INF. После этого ничего не изменилось, в общем уже два дня в свободное время пытаюсь как-то найти решение этой проблемы, но в конечном итоге всегда меня преследует 404 (если JS код просто запихнуть в HTML всё работает).

В HTML указывал путь к JS файлу всеми возможными способами, последний:

```
<script th:src="@{/static/js/script.js}"></script>
```

Прикрепляю папочную структуру которая сейчас.

[image: структура]

Буду благодарен если подскажете каким образом и что необходимо сделать чтобы иметь возможность подключать static файлы.

Comment: Попробуйте в `th:src` из пути убрать "static"

Comment: @Byb убрал, но все равно net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) :(

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась добавлением в web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

в /resources/* путь к папке с static относительно WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

Я с таким не работал но полагаю следующее:
1.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/js/");
```

говорит о том что "все запросы на сервер у которых урл начинается на `/js` это статика и искать нужно в `/WEB-INF/static/js/`"
2.
`<script th:src="@{/static/js/script.js}"></script>`
`th:src` это тег thymeleaf
 говорит о том что src будет вычислено относительно контекста приложения
таким образом скрипт будет искаться по пути `CONTEXT/static/js/script.js`, а маппинг в пункте 1 у вас настроен для путей `/js/**`
**Вариант 1:** попробуйте изменить тег скрипт `<script th:src="@{/js/script.js}"></script>`
**Вариант 2:** попробуйте заменить `.addResourceHandler("/js/**")` на `.addResourceHandler("/static/js/**")`


3. Если не поможет зайдите в devtools браузера, посмотрите куда браузер делает запрос на скрипт - во вкладке network можно посмотреть точный урл запроса - и поиграйтесь с ним (скопируйте урл и добавьте /static, уберите /static... посмотрите на поведение, откроет ли скрипт или нет)

Comment: Как мне кажется, `addResourceHandler` тут недостаточно. И вот это - добавьте, уберите, не меняет суть проблемы. Если не решить проблему, то поиграйтесь devyools-ом с url не поможет.

Comment: поиграться с devtools для того чтобы найти урл по котормоу получится достучаться до своего JS файла -> отсюда сделать логичные выводы как параметр addResourceHandler связан с урлом =)

Comment: Пусть тогда ОП поиграется с devtools-ом пока не настучит работающий url :\ К сожалению, такой ответ нельзя назвать правильным.

Comment: resourcehandler никак не способствовал решению проблемы :(